# SSL Certificate no WWW Apache (ModRewrite) EV

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

ModRewrite can easily handle stripping the www off the front of my domain.
In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But with SSL, the certificate check comes before the .htaccess rewrite, causing certificate error.
I would rather not buy an SSL certificate for the www only to redirect it.
Can you offer me a smarter solution?
(btw EV Certificates are not available as wildcards)

Comment: You don't have access to httpd.conf?

Answer (score 3):

You can get certificates with multiple domain names in them. Get one with `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`. I think it's also possible to buy "wildcard" certificates that will match any subdomain, but they cost much more.

Comment: Wildcard certificates cost a lot more than a normal cert (I think about 5x from Thawte)

Comment: I think the cheapest is still GoDaddy. Wildcard certs cost $180/year, with them, but you can get a 5-domain cert for $90.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation you could look into [cacert](http://www.cacert.org).

After you are assured by enough people to gain 50 'points',
you can create your own server certs, as many as you want.

Normaly you will be 'assured' by someone by meeting with him/her in real life, and showing some kind of ID (drivers license, passport).

For more info read the site, or you pm me.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, two options show promise:
1) When a secure connection is required, link to https://domain.com
Keeping part of your .htaccess redirection

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

will prevent www.domain.com, and hopefully minimise https://www.domain.com
2) As others have suggested, get a separate certificate for https://www.domain.com
[startssl.com](http://startssl.com) have free certificates, suitable for a redirection only job like this.

Answer (score 1):

Many SSL Certificate providers, including DigiCert, GlobalSign, and possibly GoDaddy, will put the www in a certificate for free as a Subject Alternative Name. This means the certificate will work for both paypal.com and www.paypal.com. You can then just forward all traffic from https://www.paypal.com to https://paypal.com.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. If a user accesses www.domain.cc over SSL, then you will get a certificate error if you do not have a valid SSL certificate - even if all you want to do is redirect them to the correct site.

You will either need a new certificate for www.domain.cc, or convince your registrar to give you a wildcard certificate for *.domain.cc, or one with multiple subjectAltName properties. See http://www.crsr.net/Notes/Apache-HTTPS-virtual-host.html