# Redirect from HTTPS://WWW.DOMAIN wthout SSL to HTTPS://DOMAIN with SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I have ordered an SSL certificate which covers my root domain only and it can be successfully accessed through https://domain.com.

I have created a redirection from all requests from https://www.domain.com to the root domain.

However, when trying to access https://www.domain.com which was supposed to get redirected to https://domain.com the browser returns the following warning mentioning about a security risk of proceeding with the navigation:

> ### This is probably not the site your are looking for!
>
> You attempted to reach **www.domain.com**, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as **domain.com**. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of **www.domain.com**.
>
> You should not proceed, **especially** if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

Is it somehow possible to redirect from **www** to the **root domain** using **HTTPS** without having to order another SSL certificate for **www** only for redirections?

**PS**: *domain.com is just a placeholder to help illustrating the question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately SSL certificate negotiation happens before `mod_rewrite` rules come into effect.  THerefore even before your 301 rule can redirect URIs to `non-www` domain, browser has already received certs for `non-www` while still on `www` domain. That is the point it shows that dreaded warning to visitor that cert is invalid.

You have 2 options:

1. (**Recommended**) Most of the certs these days allow you to use `www` with TLD, check with your provided if this is the option.
2. Go for wildcard certs (more expensive).

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation! Is there any specific name for this kind of certificate mentioned on the first point? the company I bought says it is only valid for a single domain, without any sub-domain included there is also the wildcard SSL which is valid for many subdomains but that is way more expensive and not needed I guess?

Comment: regarding point 2: I would still get the warning while accessing `www` under `https` which would come before rendering the page and loading the javascript is this correct? I am not quite sure if I follow the suggestion on this one? ;)

Comment: Actually you're correct about point 2 ( I will edit it and remove ). For point 1 let me search what that cert is called.

Comment: Yes and wildcard certs are 5x more expensive I heard.

Comment: See answers on this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182192/ssl-certificate-no-www-apache-modrewrite-ev It seems many cert providers allow `www` for free.

Comment: perfect, that is great! I can see that even godaddy protects both TDL and www with a single cert. I guess the company I bought it from is not very good :) thanks for you help man